# getParentFile() crashes program

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the parent file from a path but my code keeps crashing. Even if I surround it with a try catch it still crashes. This works during the source code but as soon as I jar it up and run it, it crashes.

```
    FilePath = "\\\\Asjdevqa\\root\\JAVA\\WFPM\\files\\built\\2015\\05\\aspb.001201505201405997";
File sourcePath = new File(FilePath).getParentFile().getParentFile(); // does not run beyond this line.
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace so we'd have more idea of the reasons.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?  (Including the stack trace.)

Comment: There is no stack trace, the program just dies here. If I surround this with a try catch block there is no error thrown

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the getParentFile method during the compile process

Comment: Did not think anyone could help with this issue since it's a strange one. getParentFile() does not run. I will work without getParentFile no problem and the file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because when your run it from jar, you don't have the folder `"\\\\Asjdevqa\\root\\JAVA\\WFPM\\files\\built\\2015\\05\\aspb.001201505201405997"` in the path relative to your jar. You need to copy this folder next to where the jar you are running is.